# JavaScript proper way to handle null in JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is the code :

```
for (i = 0; i < data.RecruitingGroups.length; i++) {
        data.RecruitingGroups[i].id = i;

        if (data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule.Rules != null) {
            for (j = 0; j < data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule.Rules.length; i++) {
                data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule.Rules[j].id = j;
            }    
        } 
    }
```

Problem is that sometimes RecruitingGroups[].Rule is null. So I tried to verify it was not null before continuing and running the next for loop, but it still throws the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Rules' of null

How can i bypass this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second loop needs to increment `j++` not `i++`.   =)

Comment: i like this allen dude!

Answer (score 1):

You're testing if `Rule.Rules` is `null`. That's not the problem; `Rule` *itself* is `null`, as evidenced by the error message. You need to test both `Rule` and `Rule.Rules` if either can be null.

Try

```
if (data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule && data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule.Rules) {
```

Comment: same error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Rules' of null

Comment: Then you're accessing `Rule.Rules` somewhere else without first checking if `Rule` is not null. The code I've posted **cannot** produce that error; it's impossible for my `if` statement to attempt to access `Rule.Rules` if `Rule` is null.

Comment: Found problem i++ was in second for loop. should be j++

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule && data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule.Rules) {
        for (j = 0; j < data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule.Rules.length; i++) {
            data.RecruitingGroups[i].Rule.Rules[j].id = j;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: because Rule is the one that is null, not Rules

Comment: Your doing the same thing the original code is doing, and you're going to be producing the exact same error.

Comment: i read `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Rules' of null` meaning that `Rules` was the issue, i will correct.

Comment: Now your answer contains an obvious syntax error, and it also happens to be *identical* to my answer, except without any explanation of what was wrong or what has been fixed.

Comment: @allencoded, what is the resolution to your issue, handling Rules or both Rule and Rules

Comment: problem was in the second for loop. j++ was needed not i++